# Run iPython notebook in a GitHub (or other) page

Tags: github, jupyter-notebook

I'd like to be able to make an iPython notebook and post it in a web page where users can run it straight in the web page.  I uploaded one to GitHub and it renders as a static image but I'd like users to be able to visit the page and run the code themselves, in case I use some kind of interactive or random process.  But I also don't want to force users to have Python installed on their computer to do it.  Is that possible?

Comment: Did you look at the [Jupyter Notebook Viewer](http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/)?

Comment: @DavidCullen I just tried playing with it, it doesn't seem to provide the interactivity that I'm looking for.

Comment: Have a look at [Binder](http://mybinder.org/).

Comment: @ThomasK Binder looks fantastic, thanks!